# Grabbing correct node based on attribute with multiple nodes using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've been having some trouble writing queries in LINQ to grab the data i need from an XML file.

The XML file set up looks like this

```
<Study id ="">
  <Multi>
    <filepath id =""></filepath>
    <filepath id ="display"></filepath>
    <combined></combined>
  </Multi>
</Study>

<Study id ="">
  <Multi>
    <filepath id =""></filepath>
    <filepath id ="display"></filepath>
    <combined></combined>
  </Multi>
</Study>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the filepath node where id ="display"

```
var displaySettingsQuery = (from n in _XML.Descendants("Study").Descendants("Multi")
                                    where n.Element("Multi").Attribute("id").Value == "display"
                                    select n.Element("filepath").Value);
```

This doesn't seem to work because the Element() method only grabs the first instance of "Multi". However if I use Elements(), I get a syntax error, since Elements is a Ienumerable, so I can't call attribute directly. How would I go about iterating through the "Multi" collection in order to do my comparison?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: is Id attribute for the filepath element or Multi element? in xml, it is for filepath but your query expects it to be of Multi.

Comment: The id attribute is for the filepath element, sorry about that. After changing Multi to filepath, in my where clause, it still doesn't seem to be returning any results.

Comment: And you have one single Multi element?

Comment: There are multiple Multi elements. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easier if you make `from` clause to return `<filepath>` elements instead of `<Multi>`, because you only care about `<filepath>` in the `where` and `select` clause :

```
var displaySettingsQuery = (from n in _XML.Descendants("Study")
                                          .Elements("Multi")
                                          .Elements("filepath")
                            where n.Attribute("id").Value == "display"
                            select n.Value);
```